# Got data from firestore, But not displayed immediately

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

iam a newbie in ionic and have been making this one application. i used firestore because all of the data are either links or just strings. the fetching itself is fine, but then the data doesn't load in the homepage when i first start the app. The catch is when i redirect to other page and then come back (or simply navigate to home), the data is shown. The question is, how do i make it so the data shows on app start without having to redirect routes? thank you in advance.

i tried moving my fetch from the constructor to ngOninit, doesnt work. here's my code snippet (maybe because i do too much subscribe, idk)

```
  Data = [];
  DataPers =[];
  DataInfog=[];
  DataVid=[];
  DataVid2=[];
  Events=[];
  Award=[];
  link=[];

  constructor(
    private homes: HomeServiceService,
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string
    ) {}

  calls(){
    this.homes.getNotes().subscribe(res=>{
      this.Data = res;
    }),
    this.homes.getPers().subscribe(res=>{
      this.DataPers = res;
    }),
    this.homes.getData().subscribe(res=>{
      this.DataInfog = res;
    }),
    this.homes.getVid().subscribe(res=>{
      this.DataVid = res;
    }),
    this.homes.getVid2().subscribe(res=>{
      this.DataVid2 = res;
    }),
    this.homes.getEvent().subscribe(res=>{
      this.Events = res;
    }),
    this.homes.getAward().subscribe(res=>{
      this.Award = res;
    }),
    this.homes.getHyperlink().subscribe(res=>{
      this.link = res;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.calls();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues in your code:

1. Don't add several methods inside of one big main function, looks like a mess and not dev friendly when you need to add extra logic to any of those.
2. use a different lifecycle hook.

what does your service file that host those functions look like? maybe those need to be async/await.

Comment: basically a series of this snippet
'getPers(){
    const notesRef2 = collection(this.firestore, 'Pers');
    return collectionData(notesRef2);
  }'

Comment: maybe it's not working because theres not async/await, cannot tell without looking at a project. create a stackblitz project that replicates this issue and i can take a look. if not then you need to look around for a firebase tutorial that covers this basic logic.